# why pending orders doesn't adjusted in mql4? error: the price doesnt declared. here is the mql4 code

Tags: mql4, expert-advisor

/*here i saved my last order's open price at  op parameter.*/

double op = OrderOpenPrice();

int ticket = SendOrder(_symbol,OP_SELLSTOP,0.02,op -0.0020,100, 0,0);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are trying to change existing orders you should be using [OrderSelect()](https://docs.mql4.com/trading/orderselect) and [OrderModify()](https://docs.mql4.com/trading/ordermodify).